# How to catch an array data in ashx file?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, ashx

My AJAX Code

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "AnswerHandler.ashx",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: ({ qid: keyArray , name: sName}),
                        async: false,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            if (msg == "success") {
                                alert("answer saved successfully!");
                            }
                            else{
                                alert("answer saving failed!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Now in AnswerHandler.ashx file I get name data by following line

```
string name = context.Request.QueryString["name"];
```

But how can i get qid which is an array?

Comment: at runtime, what's the type of qid?

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, I haven't run into this before and it's a little funny how jQuery handles it.

I tried this jQuery to test passing an array:

```
var arr = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
$.ajax({
            url: "ApiPage.aspx",
            data: ({myArr: arr}),
            success: function (data) {
                // do something
            }

});
```

I was able to get the array in the .ashx like this:

```
Request.QueryString["myArr[]"].Split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling it, jQuery is going to attempt to serialize your "data" element into the query string.  I'm not sure you're data format is going to successfully serialize.  If it is, you should be able to look at the Context.Request.QueryString object and figure out how it is being formatted, and go from there.

Another approach would be to:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "AnswerHandler.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    data: ({ qid: keyArray , name: sName}),
                    async: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if (msg == "success") {
                            alert("answer saved successfully!");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("answer saving failed!");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

processData: false tells jquery not to serialize your data, but instead send it "raw" to the server.  On your server, you can use Context.Request.InputStream to read these raw bytes and deserialize the json on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AnswerHandler.ashx?qid"+125487,
        type: "GET",
        data: ({ qid: keyArray , name: sName}),
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == "success") {
            alert("answer saved successfully!");
        }
        else {
            alert("answer saving failed!");
        }
    }
});
```

And in ashx file you can get the values as

```
int attId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["qid"]);
```

in this way you can send more than one value in query string and get the values using the name of the querystring you are sending.