# DomElement.click() Event don't work in chrome,but others works

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, click

I wanna submit the form when pressing down the enter key.

C#

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  runat="server" class="login-button" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" >Login</asp:LinkButton>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('keydown ', function(event) {
    var key = {
        submit: event.keycode || event.which
    };

    if (key.submit == 13) {

        document.getElementById('LinkButton1').click();

    }
});
```

Then, I get the error in chrome 18.

> Object javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','') has no method 'click'

Comment: My bad, I thought `btnLogin_Click` was a JS function. Could you post some of the rendered HTML?

Comment: Here :<a id="LinkButton1" class="login-button" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')">Login</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13)
        __doPostBack('LinkButton1','');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a76ZY/1/)

This will call the function which is assigned to your login button's `onclick` handler when you press the Enter key in your page.

The problem you were facing is most likely because your `.click()` is a shorthand for [`.trigger('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) which is not very well supported cross-browser if the handler was assigned outside of jQuery.

Also, looking through some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134945/1331430), this seems to be the simplest way to do this.

Comment: btnLogin_Click() is a C# method?I get error again: Uncaught ReferenceError: btnLogin_Click is not defined

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the very best option, but it should work now calling the rendered function.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté will click() work on DOM nodes also or just jQuery Objects?

Comment: @sabithpocker Depends, if you wrap the DOM node in a jQuery object: `$(myNode)` the `.click()` will be executed, but it's not warranted that it'll do what you expect in every browser unless you bound the click handler with jQuery.

Comment: Thing is, `.click()` (which is a shorthand for `.trigger('click')` - check these [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) - was designed to fire handlers bound with jQuery. But for a quick rundown on how to call C# methods, this answer seems pretty straightforward: [Call C# method in javascript function directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6134945/1331430) `:)`