# Call C# method from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
if(httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
{
    <% SetText(); %>
}
```

I need to call method from code behind in javascript. Method is obviously called `SetText()` and it's void.

This I tried didn't work.

Comment: you cant do it this way, the client does not have access to server code, if you explain a bit more what you want to achieve we may be able to help more, maybe a service method?

Comment: I,m checking if connection is ok, and then call some method, as I need page to stay always up, even if connection is down. What about __doPostBack?

Comment: @elninho What? That makes no sense. If the client has downloaded the page it will always be "up". If they do something that triggers a server call then, yes, the network connection needs to be up, but there isn't anything you can do to fake that anyway (unless you're going to pre-download your whole site).

Answer (score 5):

You have to expose the C# method using a service or a handler. Depending on your architecture the handler can be implemented in different ways (MVC, .net HttpHandler, JayRock handler, etc.).
And then you have to call the method from Javascript using an AJAX request.

And remember, avoid to embed CSharp code blocks inside server side generated Javascript code.

References:

- [MSDN ASP.NET MVC overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: a CSharp HTTP handler walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [JayRock homepage](http://jayrock.berlios.de/)
- [jQuery AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, at least if you don't make an [`AJAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) request. Otherwise, it's impossible to access server-side methods via client-side(in this case via JS).

Answer (score 1):

H i answered a similar question on Calling a C# method from Javascript I provided an example using AJAX: [Call C# method in javascript function directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134882/call-c-sharp-method-in-javascript-function-directly/37752614#37752614)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The client is incapable of accessing server methods in the manner in which you specified in your question. What you want to do is not possible unless you use something like AJAX.

Please explain what you're trying to do, perhaps someone can explain a different way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make one ajax call, there you check whether the connection is ok or not. If connection is ok make the actual call there itself(in server side) and return data.

Since you made an async request you page data is not going to show any error message. Even if there is some error you will get in error handler and you know what to do when error occur.

There should not be any scenario when the client code has to contact server method directly. You can always do work around with that in case your design is like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using AJAX.

I'm currently using a HTTPHandler to make my calls via AJAX. I'm accessing my handler using a service ".asmx" with code the looks like this

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MyClass" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this link 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/

yes but it is not possible without ajax call :(.

And please make sure you have imported all the necessary jquery files and the function that you have written for ajax call should be a **"STATIC".**

rest will be cleared please follow the link